# Custom underline to fit width of contents

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I am trying to make an underline that is 50% the length of the word and centered under the word being hovered.

The width in the pseudo selector takes the width of the `nav` rather than the width of the `a` being hovered, despite selecting the `a`.

When setting the `left` property, it is static the left of the `nav` rather than left of the `a`. I need it to be relative to the item being hovered.

Here is the pertinent code:

```
nav a:hover::before{
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 10%);
    bottom: 0;
    width: 20%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #7b0700;
    content: "";
}
```

and a CodePen

http://codepen.io/WallyNally/pen/dXxrgj

Any suggestions? 
Thank you.

Comment: What exactly did you want underlined? I see the first letter of each link underlined when hovered over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost there!

Missing part:

```
nav a {
  position: relative;
}
```

Without that the line positions to some element up in DOM (with position absolute, relative, fixed, or if missing to body).

As for 50% width, I’d do that:

```
nav a:hover::before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: #7b0700;
  content: "";

  /* instead of width: */
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
```

}

Fork from your code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BzXKrB

Comment: I like your solution for 50% width without the use of the `width` attribute. Another way would be to use the CSS3 [`transform`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) attribute. I.E. `width: 50%; transform: translate(50%, 50%);`

Comment: I use left right whenever possible because with `width: 100%` it sometimes behaves tricky when scrollbar shows up. So it’s a general rule for me, as it’s safer in more situations. But there is more than one way to get there, and it all depends on individual case.

Comment: Definitely, though your solution seems to be more cross-version compatible for multiple web browsers. If you can do something without CSS3 specific attributes, then its probably going to be the better option. Nice solution!

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the insight! And nice tip on using left/right instead of width.